# is this the icon for Nullsoft Installer?

Tags: icons, installation

does anyone here know what company this icon belongs to. lot of installers seem to have it. I did a Google image search, but can't pinpoint it. It looks like a dog on a trash can.

the image of the picture is on this forum post

http://forum.pcmech.com/showthread.php?t=233910

Answer (score 1):

It's a Llama on a trash can. Specifically Mike the Llama. It belongs to [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net). That's the default icon for uninstallers.